# If and how can I set up an ACCDB file with version number?

Tags: c#, ms-access, exe

I am writing a c#-program that should check the programversion of a given link:

```
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filePath);
string version = versionInfo.ProductVersion; // Will typically return "1.0.0"
MessageBox.Show("File version:" + version);
```

If I set the ***filePath*** to for example *C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe* the version of Notepad is given. Setting the path to ***test.accdb*** (Microsoft Access 2007) the version string is empty.

How or is it generally possible to set up a version in Access?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to File | Options | Current Database | Application Title   and set a value.  I prefer a different approach: Create a table to contain Ver#, Date Released, Etc. That way you can make use of other methods to insure all users have the correct version. For example, lets say you place the current version on the server, then place copies on workstations. When the user opens the database, have the startup form check the local version against the server version and halt if outdated.

Comment: thx but I don't want to change the title of the application. An extra table woud be possible and I will do it this way if it is not possible to set up a version of an access file. the rest of your discription is exactly what my program does.